# Finder 'Quick Look' (space bar) in Mountain Lion (10.8) doesn't display full image anymore...

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mountain-lion, quicklook

In Lion and Snow Leopard hitting the space bar in finder on any image would display that image at its exact dimensions or as close as it could get without bleeding past my display margins. Now in Mountain Lion hitting the space bar in Finder on an image only displays a relatively large thumbnail of that image. I have to click the 'full screen' icon in order to see it as any bigger.

Anybody know how to get Quick Look to reveal the full size of the image by just hitting the space bar like it used to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this? Also, you might consider posting on apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hatch, do you have a new Macbook Pro with Retina display?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yup.

Comment: Note that QuickLook displays images in their *original* size if possible. Small images (e.g. 500x500 pixels) have always been displayed quite small, and for you, anything below ~2560x1600 will not use anything resembling the full screen: It now takes 4x bigger images due to the retina screen. I don't think this has anything to do with Mountain Lion, you just bought a new Mac with extremely high pixel density. In other words, this is by design.

Comment: @DanielBeck , I'm not sure about that. I had it happen to me the other day and it immediately caught my attention, I didn't research/screenshot at the time. I'm on a 2012 MBP NON-retina (hi-res though). with an extended desktop set-up with 1600x900 on an external monitor as my primary desktop, and 1600x1050 on my built-in which is at 0%brightness most of the time with nothing on it. I don't remember what image file/type, but I checked now and jpg, png, raw, all up to 3888x2592 show up on both displays. Further, I _do_ remember that it was a fairly small file, that should have displayed fully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to address the particular issue you are describing, but the following may help, depending on how you utilize Quick Look (QL):

Open QL and manually resize the window; the dimensions of the window will remain the same as you browse through the file system using the arrow keys or mouse. Any images, videos, documents, etc will be scaled to fit within the boundaries of the window, but note that the QL window **must** remain open during this process.

QL is effectively useless for low resolution content, particularly on the rMBP. It would be beneficial to scale content below some specific resolution. You can provide feedback to Apple [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).